# python user input without console

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x

I have a process that runs in the background using pythonw (.pyw instead of .py) to not show console. as I am reformatting said process for distribution I need it to preform some first run questions that need answering. making the user fill out a generated text file would work but is not user friendly. it is sadly not as simple as

```
config = {}
config['user'] = input('new user data: ')
```

because there is no console to request the input it will hang unanswered

as I am tying to make this for systems that may not have custom modules I'm trying to not make dependencies. any good way to ask multiple questions without the console to host the input using the base python install.

Comment: Will your target systems have a GUI?  If you don't have stdin, and you don't have a GUI, you're sort of running out of options here.  I mean, I suppose you could host a configuration web page on a local network, but if you don't have networking either, that's a no-go.

Comment: not sure what you mean by GUI in this context if it is the Python Shell that is what pythonw hides. I have been looking into sub processing but not having a lot of success since help pages only explain non-interactive processes

Comment: No, I was thinking of embedded systems which do not support any UI whatsoever (or at least, nothing beyond basic text I/O).

Comment: I only need some strings from the user if basic python has GUI that can accept strings or multiple choice that would be great

Comment: Try [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tkinter.html).

Comment: if that was given as an answer I would green check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emulate builtin `input()` using `tkinter`, you could use `askstring()`:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # hide main window

config = {}
config['user'] = askstring("Title", 'new user data: ')
```

Comment: this fixes my next issue of retrieving data from the TK odd that none of the tutorials cover that

Comment: `root.deiconify() # retrieve the main window`